# Invalid property: TZID with PHP generated .ics file

Tags: php, timezone, icalendar

I am trying to create a valid .ics file, but I am receiving the following error when I try to valid it:

```
Error:  Error was: Invalid property: TZID
Cause:  Sorry, I couldn't get an exact cause.
(when tested on this page: http://severinghaus.org/projects/icv/)
```

My .ics file looks like this:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
VERSION:2.0
PRODID:-//BenchApp/BAcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN
CALSCALE:GREGORIAN
TZID:America/Vancouver
X-WR-TIMEZONE:America/Vancouver
X-WR-CALNAME:Beavers
X-WR-CALDESC:Team Schedule
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20160913T220000
UID:58756a0d39f0e
DTSTAMP:20160913T200000
SUMMARY:Hornets vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-81915
DTSTART:20160913T200000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20160922T203000
UID:58756a0d3a069
DTSTAMP:20160922T183000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Thrashers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-86585
DTSTART:20160922T183000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20160929T001500
UID:58756a0d3a187
DTSTAMP:20160928T221500
SUMMARY:Meh8s vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-86586
DTSTART:20160928T221500
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161002T170000
UID:58756a0d3a27a
DTSTAMP:20161002T150000
SUMMARY:Predators vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-86587
DTSTART:20161002T150000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161015T231500
UID:58756a0d3a3d8
DTSTAMP:20161015T220000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Cutting Edges Beircraft
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98117
DTSTART:20161015T220000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161019T224500
UID:58756a0d3a52c
DTSTAMP:20161019T213000
SUMMARY:Thrashers vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98118
DTSTART:20161019T213000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161023T204500
UID:58756a0d3a667
DTSTAMP:20161023T193000
SUMMARY:No Ma'am vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98119
DTSTART:20161023T193000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161103T211500
UID:58756a0d3a7a5
DTSTAMP:20161103T200000
SUMMARY:Lululemon Wreckers vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98120
DTSTART:20161103T200000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161117T224500
UID:58756a0d3a930
DTSTAMP:20161117T213000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Predators
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98122
DTSTART:20161117T213000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161120T204500
UID:58756a0d3aa57
DTSTAMP:20161120T193000
SUMMARY:Meh8s vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98123
DTSTART:20161120T193000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161130T220000
UID:58756a0d3ab66
DTSTAMP:20161130T204500
SUMMARY:Cutting Edges Beircraft vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98124
DTSTART:20161130T204500
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161203T191500
UID:58756a0d3ac75
DTSTAMP:20161203T180000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Thrashers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98125
DTSTART:20161203T180000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161210T161500
UID:58756a0d3adc9
DTSTAMP:20161210T150000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. No Ma'am
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98126
DTSTART:20161210T150000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20161216T220000
UID:58756a0d3aec3
DTSTAMP:20161216T204500
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Lululemon Wreckers
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-98127
DTSTART:20161216T204500
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170104T233000
UID:58756a0d3afb2
DTSTAMP:20170104T221500
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Hornets
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115210
DTSTART:20170104T221500
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170108T174500
UID:58756a0d3b12a
DTSTAMP:20170108T163000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. No Ma'am
LOCATION:UBC Thunderbird, 6066 Thunderbird Blvd., Vancouver, BC, Canada
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115211
DTSTART:20170108T163000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170121T114500
UID:58756a0d3b258
DTSTAMP:20170121T103000
SUMMARY:No Ma'am vs. Beavers
LOCATION:UBC Thunderbird, 6066 Thunderbird Blvd., Vancouver, BC, Canada
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115212
DTSTART:20170121T103000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170127T220000
UID:58756a0d3b3a4
DTSTAMP:20170127T204500
SUMMARY:Lululemon Wreckers vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115213
DTSTART:20170127T204500
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170207T194500
UID:58756a0d3b4e4
DTSTAMP:20170207T183000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Hornets
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115214
DTSTART:20170207T183000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170212T161500
UID:58756a0d3b710
DTSTAMP:20170212T150000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Predators
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115215
DTSTART:20170212T150000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170219T144500
UID:58756a0d3b8e5
DTSTAMP:20170219T133000
SUMMARY:Meh8s vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115216
DTSTART:20170219T133000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170221T224500
UID:58756a0d3baeb
DTSTAMP:20170221T213000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Hornets
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115217
DTSTART:20170221T213000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170228T211500
UID:58756a0d3bcd6
DTSTAMP:20170228T200000
SUMMARY:Cutting Edges Beircraft vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115218
DTSTART:20170228T200000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170309T224500
UID:58756a0d3bec7
DTSTAMP:20170309T213000
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. No Ma'am
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115219
DTSTART:20170309T213000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170317T233000
UID:58756a0d3c08e
DTSTAMP:20170317T221500
SUMMARY:Beavers vs. Lululemon Wreckers
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115220
DTSTART:20170317T221500
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170322T211500
UID:58756a0d3c1af
DTSTAMP:20170322T200000
SUMMARY:Hornets vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Thunderbird
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115221
DTSTART:20170322T200000
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
BEGIN:VEVENT
DTEND:20170324T233000
UID:58756a0d3c2e3
DTSTAMP:20170324T221500
SUMMARY:Predators vs. Beavers
LOCATION:Father Bauer
URL;VALUE=URI:http://www.benchapp.com/schedule/game-115222
DTSTART:20170324T221500
LAST-MODIFIED:20170110T151109
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Can anyone spot an issue that might be related to my timezone settings?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed no TZID property at th VCALENDAR level, so it is complaining about line 5:

`TZID:America/Vancouver`

On the other hand, all of your DTSTART and DTEND should have a TZID parameter, e.g.

```
DTSTART;TZID=America/Vancouver:20160922T183000
```

In theory, your file should also start with the VTIMEZONE definition corresponding to this particular timezone. Some clients may not like a TZID without a proper definition.

Comment: So you think I should have VTIMEZONE before I do VCALENDAR?

Comment: Also, do you think I need to be as thorough as adding this block: `BEGIN:VTIMEZONE
TZID:America/Los_Angeles
X-LIC-LOCATION:America/Los_Angeles
BEGIN:DAYLIGHT
TZOFFSETFROM:-0800
TZOFFSETTO:-0700
TZNAME:PDT
DTSTART:19700308T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=3;BYDAY=2SU
END:DAYLIGHT
BEGIN:STANDARD
TZOFFSETFROM:-0700
TZOFFSETTO:-0800
TZNAME:PST
DTSTART:19701101T020000
RRULE:FREQ=YEARLY;BYMONTH=11;BYDAY=1SU
END:STANDARD
END:VTIMEZONE`

Comment: Right, except you need to have a VTIMEZONE that corresponds to the TZID used in the DTSTART. So it would be America/Vancouver, and not America/Los_Angeles

Comment: So then I'd have to figure out the timezone information for every timezone I offer? It's not overkill?